# efficient way to draw pixel art in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pygame, draw, pixel

I'm making a very simple pixel art software in pygame. My logic was creating a grid class, which has a 2D list, containing 0's. When I click, the grid approximates the row and column selected, and mark the cell with a number, corresponding to the color. For simplicity, let's say '1'.

The code works correctly, but It's slow. If the number of rows and columns is less or equal than 10, It works perfectly, but if It's more, it's very laggy.

I think the problem is that I'm updating the entire screen everytime, and, since the program has to check EVERY cell, It can't handle a bigger list

```
import pygame
from grid import Grid
from pincel import Pincel
from debugger import Debugger
from display import Display
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer_music.load("musica/musica1.wav")
pygame.mixer_music.play(-1)

width = 1300
height = 1300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366, 768), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("SquareDraw")

#Grid Creator
numberOfRows = 25
numberOfColumns = 25
grid = Grid(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns)

# Medidas
basicX = width / numberOfColumns
basicY = height / numberOfRows

#Tool Creator
pincel = Pincel(2)


#variáveis de controle
running = 1

#Initial values
grid.equipTool(pincel)

#variáveis de controle de desenho
clicking = 0


def drawScreen(screen, grid, rows, columns, basicX, basicY):
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            if grid[i][j]:
                print('yes')
                print(i, j)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (j * basicX, i * basicY, basicX, basicY))



while running:

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    Display.drawScreen(screen, grid.board, grid.getRows(), grid.getColumns(), basicX, basicY)
    pygame.display.flip()


    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            running = 0
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or clicking:
            clicking = 1
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            Debugger.printArray2D(grid.board)
            print('')
            xInGrid = int(x / basicX)
            yInGrid = int(y / basicY)
            grid.ferramenta.draw(grid.board, xInGrid, yInGrid)
            Debugger.printArray2D(grid.board)
            print('')
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            clicking = 0
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width = event.w
            height = event.h
            basicX = width / numberOfColumns
            basicY = height / numberOfRows
            print(width, height)


pygame.quit()
```

The class grid contains the 2D list. The class "Pincel" marks the cells and The class "Debugger" is just for printing lists or anything related to debugging.

Is there a way to update only the part of the screen that was changed? If so, how can I apply that in my logic?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Use the grid array to store the on\off blocks of the screen. It only gets read when the screen is resized and needs a full redraw
- When a new rectangle is turned on, draw the rectangle directly in the event handler and update the grid array. There is no need to redraw the entire screen here.
- In the resize event, reset the screen mode to the new size then redraw the entire screen using the grid array. This is the only time you need to do a full redraw.

Here is the updated code:

```
import pygame
#from grid import Grid
#from pincel import Pincel
#from debugger import Debugger
#from display import Display
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#pygame.mixer_music.load("musica/musica1.wav")
#pygame.mixer_music.play(-1)

width = 1000
height = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("SquareDraw")

#Grid Creator
numberOfRows = 250  
numberOfColumns = 250
#grid = Grid(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns)
grid = [[0 for x in range(numberOfRows)] for y in range(numberOfColumns)]  # use array for grid: 0=white, 1=black

# Medidas
basicX = width / numberOfColumns
basicY = height / numberOfRows

#Tool Creator
#pincel = Pincel(2)

#xx
running = 1

#Initial values
#grid.equipTool(pincel)

#xx
clicking = 0

def drawScreen(screen, grid, basicX, basicY):  # draw rectangles from grid array
    for i in range(numberOfColumns):
        for j in range(numberOfRows):
            if grid[i][j]:
                #print('yes')
                #print(i, j)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (j * basicX, i * basicY, basicX, basicY))

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # start screen

while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            running = 0
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or clicking:  # mouse button down
            clicking = 1
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            #Debugger.printArray2D(grid.board)
            #print('')
            xInGrid = int(x / basicX)
            yInGrid = int(y / basicY)
            grid[yInGrid][xInGrid] = 1  # save this point = 1, for screen redraw (if resize)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (xInGrid * basicX, yInGrid * basicY, basicX, basicY))  # draw rectangle
            #grid.ferramenta.draw(grid.board, xInGrid, yInGrid)
            #Debugger.printArray2D(grid.board)
            #print('')
            pygame.display.flip()  # update screen
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            clicking = 0
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:  # screen resized, must adjust grid height, width
            width = event.w
            height = event.h
            basicX = width / numberOfColumns
            basicY = height / numberOfRows
            #print(width, height)
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)  # reset screen with new height, width
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # clear screen
            drawScreen(screen, grid, basicX, basicY)  # redraw rectangles
            pygame.display.flip()  # update screen


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you a lot. That was exactly what I needed. I'll keep this in mind when I don't have to draw the entire screen, in other projects :)